# Attach "Header A" to "Details A"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report uses Crystal Reports and C#. It's quite complex, with vertical and horizontal pages, many different lists of data, etc.

I have a main report where each "details section" is a subreport, some subreports are horizontal, and some are vertical, some of them must have a header and others must have a different one.

What I want to know if it is possible to associate a page header ("header section a") with a specific details section("detail section a").

I know it is possible to suppress a page header depending on page number (with a formula similar than "PageNumber<4"), but as list are variable and can use one or more pages, it is not possible to know in which page a subreport starts and ends.

Is there any way to create a formula to suppress a page header where specify something like "if this page is for details section b suppress this header page". It could be also great to detect the first page of the subreport so a different page header could be used depending if it is the first page or not.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you, you have main report with sections like

```
detail section a
detail section b
detail section c
....
....
detail section n
```

In each section you have different sub-report with different formatting. So lets say you have next

```
detail section a - subreport_a
detail section b - subreport_b
detail section c - subreport_c
....
....
detail section n - subreport_n
```

In each subreport you can add report/group headers/footers which can be used for your "customized headers". No need for using underlined logic (if then else for suppressing).